# Generate a height data table from 2 rasters at a given position - QGIS 3.32.0-Lima

Tags: qgis, spatial-statistics

I have two raster height maps and a (vector?) layer with points.
The goal is to generate a statistic that looks something like this:

```
Point 1:
Layer 1: 100m
Layer 2: 300m
Point 2:
Layer 1: 70m
Layer 2: 300m
...
```

Afterwards, it should be possible to import the statistic with tools like libreoffice calc, excel, ..., so I can calculate the difference between them.

**Is there already a built-in option for this in QGIS and if not, how can I generate such a file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Refactor fields to calculate the two columns.

Fetch the value of the raster at the point locations with the expressions:
`raster_value(layer:='raster1', band:=1, point:=$geometry)`

`raster_value(layer:='raster2', band:=1, point:=$geometry)`

Replace `'raster1'` / `'raster2'` with the names of your raster layers.

[image]

Another option is to [Sample Raster Values](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgisrastersampling) twice

Comment: Instead of then importing it to Excel after follwoing this step above you can then also just calculate the height by adding a new column to your points-layer and calculate it with the field calculator by "Raster2" - "Raster1" [insert the names of your columns]

Comment: @BERA Thanks! As soon, as it works, I mark it as an answer!